# App with Multiple Components

Tags: sapui5

I want to create an  application with multiple components to separate each applications.

#### My Project Structure

[image: Project structure]

#### My Main Page

[image: main page]

How can I change the application when clicking on menu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Component reuse in manifest.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343788/component-reuse-in-manifest-json-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can always dynamically load components like follows:

```
var oComponent = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer("componentID", {
  name: "apps.ToolsNamingFileGenerator"
});
```

Just place it in your UI wherever you want. The Component should inherit context and models from the Component it is instantiated from.

BR
Chris

Comment: What do you mean about place it in your UI? We do we have to put the new loaded component?

Comment: Just add it in any aggregation of your existing UI or use placeAt()